# Can't login due to kwallet error with nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm

I have a workstation with 2 nVidia Quadro K620 video cards and 3 monitors. In order to drive all 3 monitors I have to have the nVidia 361.45.11 drivers installed. After applying updates recently, I get an error when trying to login where the screen goes black after I enter the password and then returns to the password prompt screen. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I can login via the cli, and in `/var/log/auth.log` I get errors like:

```
Jun 13 14:24:08 techne lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue or suggestions for fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. On a Dell Precision 3620, you have to go into the BIOS and disable Secure Boot. After that, you are able to use the nVidia drivers.